# Android: dismissing dialogs containing listeners

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm working with two classes, and model class and a dialog class in android.  The model class keeps a list of listeners, which the dialog adds to.

```
public class SmartChannelModel {

    private List<OnResultsChanged> mOnResultsChanged
    public interface OnResultsChanged {
        void onResultsChanged(int changed);
    }

    public SmartChannelModel() {
        mOnResultsChanged = new List<OnResultsChanged>();
    }

    public void addResultListener(OnResultsChanged listener) {
        mOnResultsChanged.add(listener);
    }
}
```

And my dialog class:

```
public class InfoDialog extends AppCompatDialog {
    private SmartChannelModel model;
    public InfoDialog(Context context, SmartChannelModel model) {
        super(context);
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void update() {
        //do some stuff
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        model.addOnResultsChanged(new OnResultsChanged() {
            @Override
            void onResultsChanged(int changed) {
                update();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I create and dismiss this dialog, will garbage collection ever be performed on it since the dialog added a listener to the model class?  Do I need to specifically remove any listeners that I've added?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  far as i know Yes if there is no other reference to it anywhere in the class.